# Solve $x\log x=y$

Tags: logarithms

I have the following equation, $x\log x=y$.

Is it possible to solve $x$ in terms of $y$.

I think it is not possible but I am not sure.

Comment: The answer is quite complicated, see [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*log%28x%29+%3D+y+solve+for+x)

Comment: It is one of the most beautiful functions (after $e^x$ and $\log(x)$)

Answer (score 2):

$x$ must be positive, for the $\log$ to exist, so you can write $x=e^u$ and the equation becomes:

$$ue^u=y$$

This equation is well known, and has no solution in elementary function, but in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

$$u=\mathrm{W}(y)$$

Hence

$$x=e^{\mathrm{W}(y)}$$